# Angular 7: ¿Cómo poner una imagen (responsive) como background de varios componentes?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular7

En un proyecto **Angular 7 con ng-bootstrap** (es decir, incluye css y scss de bootstrap sin jQuery), estoy intentando poner una imagen como background de los tres componentes que se van a pintar en la portada, pero la estoy declarando como **img** solo en uno de ellos (**cover.component**) con **position:absolute**.

Agradecería enormemente cualquier ayuda.

Tengo básicamente **dos problemas**:

1. No he conseguido que la imagen sea responsive;
2. He tenido que poner el footer "fixed-bottom" para que no quedara flotando en mitad de la imagen y se me montan los datos.

La **estructura** de los componentes es:

- header.component
- cover.component
- footer.component

Se están pintando en **app.component.html**

```
<app-header #header></app-header>
<app-cover [seccion]="header.content">
<app-footer></app-footer>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**cover.component.html** *(la imagen se declara en la línea 2)

```
<div class="container text-center pb-5">
<img src="assets\pictures\bg4.jpg" class="img-fluid" style="position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0; z-index: -100; opacity: 0.75;">
  <div class="row pb-sm-0 my-5">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
      <p class="lead text-center " style="opacity: 3; font-size: 30px">
        <b>Únete a la REVOLUCIÓN</b>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row py-2">
    <div class="col w-auto h-auto mx-auto">
      <div id="sandclockDesc" *ngIf="seccion==='sandclock'">
        <p class="text-justify">
          <!--Aqui va el texto1-->
        </p>
      </div>
      <div id="seniorDescr" *ngIf="seccion==='senior'">
        <p class="text-justify">
          <!--Aqui va el texto2-->
        </p>
      </div>
      <div id="robotcopDescr" *ngIf="seccion==='robotcop'">
        <p class="text-justify">
          <!--Aqui va el texto3-->
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Respecto al problema del footer pongo el código por si fuera necesario

**footer.component.html**

```
<div class="container fixed-bottom">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="text-center align-self-center p-3 col-md-12">
      <!--<p class="text-white">-->
      <p>
        <b><b>Time Force Tech. S.L.</b></b>&nbsp;
        <br>Calle Sta. María Mazzarello, 1
        <br>Sevilla, CP 41005&nbsp;
        <br>P:&nbsp;954 63 23 47
      </p>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-around">
          <a href="#">
            <i class="d-block fab fa-facebook text-dark fa-lg mx-4"></i>
          </a>
          <a href="#">
            <i class="d-block fab fa-instagram text-dark fa-lg mx-4"></i>
          </a>
          <a href="#">
            <i class="d-block fab fa-twitter text-dark fa-lg mx-4"></i>
          </a>
          <a href="#">
            <i class="d-block fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-up text-dark fa-lg mx-4"></i>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Adjunto las imágenes

[image: Al_compilar]
[image: Al_desplegar_texto]
[image: Al_comprobar_responsive]

Answer (score 0):

Con respecto a la duda uno, utilizando Bootstrap, puedes colocarle a la imagen la clase `img-fluid`, tal como se especifica [en este enlace](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/images/#responsive-images).

Con respecto al segundo caso, has una clase CSS con esto:

```
.footer {
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 60px; /* Altura a tu gusto */
   line-height: 60px; /* Verticalmente centrado */
   background-color: #f5f5f5; /* Por si le quieres colocar un color */
}
```

Comment: Muy buenas, gracias en primer lugar.

Respecto a la opción del footer, tampoco me ayuda. No es muy distinto de de fixed-bottom y me da más problemas. Creo que solucionando el primer problema se solucionará el segundo.

Respecto a lo de img-fluid, ya está puesto (donde pone en la línea 2 **class="img-fluid"**). 

El problema en mi opinión va más por dónde he declarado la imagen (ahí en mitad de un componente) y con **position:absolute**.

Comment: Eres capaz de hacerlo en el `body`?

Comment: No, porque no es una imagen que vaya a estar ahí permanentemente. Al repintar la página con routing el fondo deja de ser una imagen para pasar a ser un color.

Comment: Entonces has un componente padre y que los demas sean hijos. En el componente padre asigna la imagen.

Answer (score 0):

Tambien he tenido bastante problemas con poner la imagen en background desde una clase css aparte , lo más recomendable es que la apliques como un estilo en línea, a cada elemento que necesitas que tenga esta imagen de background, es la manera más rápida y que siempre funciona .

```
      <div Style="background-image:url(".../")">
         <div>
             <!--aqui pones el texto-->
         </div>       
      </div>
```