# Angular no reconoce la ruta estatica de una imagen desde css3

Tags: javascript, html5, css3, angular7

Actualmente estoy diseñando una página con `angular 7`, sin embargo al intentar agregar un **background-image** desde el `css` a la plantilla `html` no me reconoce la ruta que le asigno, la cual se encuentra contenida en mi carpeta assets, adjunto imagen [image: Imagen de ruta proyecto angular]

el código `css` con problemas es el siguiente:

```css
.home-inner {
  background-image: url(./assets/img/intro.jpg)
}
```

he probado con **"/"** o poniendo **".."** intentado subir el nivel donde se encuentra la carpeta pero no muestra la imagen como **background** o me arroja el mensaje de error como se muestra en la imagen adjunta

Comment: Hola @Erick91 Intenta poner ../assets/img/intro.jpg esto sucede porque están en carpetas diferentes, el ./ se utiliza cuando están en el mismo directorio.

Comment: Comprendo, lee este post, tal vez te ayude: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/231141/angular-7-cómo-poner-una-imagen-responsive-como-background-de-varios-compone

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que partir de tu navbar.component.css hacia arriba en la estructura de carpetas hasta llegar a src, dirigiendote despues a assets y lo siguiente. Prueba con:

```
.home-inner{
    background-image:url(../../../assets/img/intro.jpg)
}
```

Truco: Cuando utilizas el punto en un ruta te estas refiriendo que partes del archivo actual. El "./" se refiere a la misma carpeta.